# How to fix the position of the label of textbox In Google app maker?

Tags: javascript, css, google-app-maker

I was trying to create a form using Google app maker. And I created a field textbox. I created a box using CSS. But the problem I'm facing is the Label of the box is floating. Like when I first enter in the form the label for the textbox "Enter your name" is inside the box. 
what I have right now is this
Before Focus 
[image]

after focus : 
[image]

But when user start to type it it goes up. But I want to have a fix position for it. Something Like this. 
[image]
so far I only have this CSS styles:

```
.app-Email-Name {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.75px 0.75px 0.75px 0.75px;
  border-color: gray;
  border-radius: 5px;

}
```

Comment: If you want to have a fixed label, then don't use the label field of the TextBox widget, instead, just add a label above the widget and set the text value to whatever you need.

Comment: Fixed the problem By using Position of the label as "static" to override the app maker's default absolute